# Buttons created in a loop are all doing the same thing when clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I am currently trying to do some stuff in Java, using `ButtonColumn` from the internet, which allows me to create clickable button inside a `JTable` cell. But I am in need to make multiple buttons and for each button specified it´s own parameter for its action. So I have this code:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
dtm.setNumRows(uziv.size());
int riadok = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < uziv.size(); i++) {
    jTable1.setValueAt(uziv.get(i).getMeno(), riadok, 0);
    jTable1.setValueAt(uziv.get(i).getPriezvisko(), riadok, 1);
    jTable1.setValueAt(uziv.get(i).getEmail(), riadok, 2);
    jTable1.setValueAt(uziv.get(i).getLogin(), riadok, 3);
    int idUz = uziv.get(i).getId();

    Action ban = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            int modelRow = Integer.valueOf(e.getActionCommand());
            db.zabanujUzivatela(db.selectId(idUz));
        }
    };

    ButtonColumn col = new ButtonColumn(jTable1, ban, 4);    
    riadok++;
}
```

But the problem is that my `idUziv` even that it´s changing during the for cyclus, at the end when I run my program and click on any button, all buttons are pointing on the same `idUziv` when their action is executed. And I am really out of ideas how else I can do this. I need to make it like the first button click would point to `idUziv` with value 1 for example, second with value 2 and so on... Do you have any idea how to id ? Or is it even possible ?
Thank you very much for every answer

Comment: An [mcve] would help immensely

Comment: Why ? what you don´t understand about what I wrote ?

Comment: I don't understand what is causing your bug -- and neither do you.

Comment: But camickr *might* have the solution. 1+

Comment: `using ButtonColumn from the internet,` - As found in [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ButtonColumn col = new ButtonColumn(jTable1, ban, 4);

You can't create a `ButtonColumn` for each row. The class name is "...Column". The editor is for the entire column. There is only one Action for all the rows. So the Action needs to be written generically so it can work for all rows.

> But I am in need to make multiple buttons and for each button specified it´s own parameter for its action.

Store the ID as part of the TableModel. So you need to create a table with a column for the ID and then set the id when you load the data into the TableModel:

```
jTable1.setValueAt(uziv.get(i).getLogin(), riadok, 3);
//int idUz = uziv.get(i).getId();
jTable1.setValueAt(uziv.get(i).getId(), riadok, 4);
```

Then you can remove the TableColumn from the JTable so the column is not visible:

```
table.removeColumn( table.getColumn(...) );
```

Now in your Action you can access the ID from the TableModel for the selected row.

Or another option is to imbed the ID in the text for the button column as was demonstrated in the example from the `TableButtonColumn` so that you see "Login ID1". Then you just get the text from the model and parse out the last word.